# Adding label and text box control to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlabel

I would like to know what code to insert and where to add a simple label that can just say the word "Label" and a input text box that I can enter a number.

```
public CalculateDimensions() {

    JTabbedPane Tab = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("First Tab");
    Tab.addTab("One", jplInnerPanel1);
    Tab.setSelectedIndex(0);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel("Second Tab");
    Tab.addTab("Two", jplInnerPanel2);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel3 = createInnerPanel("Third Tab");
    Tab.addTab("Three", jplInnerPanel3);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = createInnerPanel("Fourth Tab");
    Tab.addTab("Four", jplInnerPanel4);
    JPanel jplInnerPanel5 = createInnerPanel("Fifth Tab");
    Tab.addTab("Five", jplInnerPanel5);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    add(Tab);
}
protected JPanel createInnerPanel(String text) {
    JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel(text);
    jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
    return jplPanel;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculations");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(new CalculateDimensions(),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: The code can be inserted within the first tab.

Comment: "The code can be inserted within the first tab."  Yes, of course it can.  In fact, it can be inserted into any tab you like.  If you are having a specific problem doing that, I suggest you ask a specific question.  Also note that for better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  I solved the problem in an SSCCE earlier today, that took less time than typing this comment.

Comment: I thought my comment was specific.  I said I don't know what code to insert or where to insert it.  How do you post an SSCCE?  I'm not sure what that is.  Thanks

Comment: Which word of SSCCE do you not understand?  I linked to the complete description.  If you do not understand it, or cannot frame more specific questions than "How do you post an SSCCE?" then I cannot help you further.

Comment: Ok, going with my first comment.  Right now when the code runs it produces five tabs.  With each tab it adds a statement "One", "Two" and so on.  I would like to know how and where to insert a left align label and a text box next to it.  I have done a lot of research on this and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The Swing tutorial is an excellent resource for building GUIs.

Take a look at the visual guide and click on the components you want for detailed how to guides for creating text boxes, and other items.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html

Comment: @Mike, give it a shot, take a look at the examples.  If you run into trouble make sure your question here is specific.  Show what you have, what it does and why it is not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

in your `public static void main()` method you should not instantiate `JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculations");`

This is where you are going wrong!

That line should read:

```
CalculateDimensions frame = new CalculateDimensions("Calculations");
```

You will also need to change the line says

```
public class CalculateDimensions {
```

(it's near the top) says

```
public class CalculateDimensions extends JFrame {
```

then inside the method called `public class CalculateDimensions {` you need to add a line after `JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("First Tab");` which says

```
jplInnerPanel1.add(new JLabel("Label");
```