# Adding tabs, labels, and text boxes

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding label and text box control to GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236575/adding-label-and-text-box-control-to-gui)

Can someone help me out writing a small code in java that inserts one tab and within that tab one label and one text box.  I have read a lot of information about this and have tried over and over but can't figure it out.  I actually need it for multilpe tabs, labels, and text boxes, but if someone can help me get started I think I can apply that to what I need to do to create more.

Thanks so much

Comment: Noboby can help you if you give insufficient information. What is a tab or a label? Are you talking about AWT or Swing or something completely different?

Comment: @Mike, you have already asked about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236575/adding-label-and-text-box-control-to-gui

Comment: @MPi  I'm trying tot create a GUI that consists of tabs across the top where I can click on each tab and within each tab there are labels and text boxes.  This is what I need help on.  If someone can get me started on the right path showing me how to do one, I can apply that to do more.

Comment: @jzd, I know I asked a similar question, but I'm not getting the help I need.  I know you had posted a link and I looked it over and tried to apply what it talks about, but I can't figure it out.  You said within that post I needed to be more specific.  I was being specific.  I said that I need to insert a label and text box field, but don't know where or how to do it.

Comment: Try it without the tab pane.  Get it working just on a JPanel, follow the tutorials then work your way up to doing it with the tabbed pane.

Comment: Mike, you should have just edited your original question rather than asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that I have implemented to remember how to use gridbaglayout.. :)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class FrmTabbedPane  extends JFrame{

    public FrmTabbedPane() {
        createGui();
    }

    private void createGui() {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", createPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab2", createPanel());
        add(tabbedPane);


    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        addLabelTextField(panel,1);
        addLabelTextField(panel,2);
        addLabelTextField(panel,3);

        return panel;
    }

    private void addLabelTextField(JPanel panel,int row) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridy = row;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(1, 5, 1, 10);
              c.weightx=0.3;  
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label");
        panel.add(label1,c);
        JTextField txtField1 = new JTextField();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.7;
        panel.add(txtField1,c);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FrmTabbedPane frm = new FrmTabbedPane();
                frm.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                frm.setSize(500, 300);
                frm.setVisible(true);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Gursel Koca, Thanks, that is what I needed.  How do you change the size of the fields?

Comment: you can use c.weightx attribute to change horizantal size of component.

Comment: If I change the number it stays the same.  I don't know if I'm doing something wrong?